# 同一ネットワーク内の2つのゲートウェイとRDP接続について

Tags: vpn, rdp

事務所内のネットワークに2回線のインターネットが接続されています。
※ビジネス電話との関係でNTTとKDDIの2回線の契約があります。

**NTT系**
RT58i：192.168.1.5
VPN設定あり

**KDDI系** (KDDI-HGWからDMZ接続)デフォルトGW
NVR830：192.168.1.10
VPN設定あり

クライアント端末のGWは基本的にKDDIへ接続されており、
リモートワークのためKDDI経由でVPN+RDP接続しています。

先日KDDI回線が不調だったためNTT回線のRT58iへもVPN設定を行いVPNの疎通も確認できたのですが、RDP接続ができませんでした。

色々とためしてみるとGWがNTTになっているときにはNTTからのRDP接続はできるが、KDDIのGW設定になっている場合はNTTからのRDP接続はNGになるようです。

KDDIの回線が復活してから逆パターンも試してみましたが同じ状況で、VPN接続をしているルーター側にGWを設定していないとRDP接続ができませんでした。

できれば保険として片方の回線がダメでももう片方の回線からRDP接続ができるとうれしいのですが、そういう事は難しいのでしょうか。

事務所に居たらKDDIの回線の調子が悪い場合、手動でNTTのGWへ変更すれば問題無く使えるのはわかるのですが、事務所に行かずに生きている方のVPNからRDP接続(入れたらGWも手動で切り替え出来る)と言った運用ができると助かるのです。

ルート設定等で可能なのでしょうか。

説明が分かりにくいかもしれませんが、どなたかお知恵をいただけると大変助かります。

---

htb様

詳しくありがとうございます

１．KDDI側は触れるのですが、NTT側は業者がVoipの設定も含めて管理しているため入れ替えは難しいかもしれません
ただ、回線バックアップが使えるような機種だと一番安心できそうですね

２．デフォルトゲートウェイを自動的に切り替えるのはbatとかですかね
各端末で常時監視するのはちょっとハードルが高そうですので調査してみます

３．VPN端末に払い出されるIPへのルート設定で良かったのですね
言われたら確かにその通りなのですが接続元のグローバルIPへのルート設定をしないといけないのかと勘違いしました

VPN払い出しIPはNTT(192.168.1.100-149)、KDDI(192.168.1.150-199)でそれぞれ違います

IP範囲を変更して考えてみましたがこんな感じで良いのでしょうか
NTT(192.168.1.96-127)
KDDI(192.168.1.128-159)

route -p add 192.168.1.96 mask 255.255.255.224 192.168.1.5
route -p add 192.168.1.128 mask 255.255.255.224 192.168.1.10

Comment: 「GWを設定」等で繰り返し書かれているGWは、RDP接続先の事務所内の端末のデフォルトゲートウェイのことを指していますか。

Comment: はいそうです
説明不足で申し訳ありません
事務所内の端末のデフォルトゲートウェイの事です

Answer (score 0, accepted):

何個か手法はあると思います。

1. WANのポートを2個以上持つVPNルーターに置き換える
   RTX1220など。
   https://network.yamaha.com/products/routers/rtx1220/index
   WAN回線のバックアップといった機能。
   https://network.yamaha.com/setting/router_firewall/internet/internet_redundancy/wan_backup/
   お金とルーター導入の技術的なハードルはありますが、堅牢かと思います。
2. 端末のデフォルトゲートウェイを自動的に変更する
   ping 8.8.8.8 など、インターネットへの疎通ができなくなったら、デフォルトゲートウェイを変更する。
   既にデフォルトゲートウェイを変更すればOKであることは確認できているので、次善の策としてはアリだと思います。
   デフォルトゲートウェイを自動的に変更するのは、別の問題を生みそうな気もします。
3. 事務所の端末にスタティックルートを書く
   VPN端末に払い出されるIPアドレス(ネットワーク)へのスタティックルートをGW宛に書く。
   VPN端末とは事務所の外のVPN接続してくる手元のパソコンを指します。払い出されるIPアドレスは質問に書かれていないので具体的に答えることはできません。
   https://www.infraexpert.com/study/routing4.html

Comment: お返事が遅くなりました
詳しくありがとうございます

１．KDDI側は触れるのですが、NTT側は業者がVoipの設定も含めて管理しているため入れ替えは難しいかもしれません
ただ、回線バックアップが使えるような機種だと一番安心できそうですね

２．デフォルトゲートウェイを自動的に切り替えるのはbatとかですかね
各端末で常時監視するのはちょっとハードルが高そうですので調査してみます

３．VPN端末に払い出されるIPへのルート設定で良かったのですね
言われたら確かにその通りなのですが接続元のグローバルIPへのルート設定をしないといけないのかと勘違いしました

VPN払い出しIPはNTT(192.168.1.100-149)、KDDI(192.168.1.150-199)でそれぞれ違います

IP範囲を変更して考えてみましたがこんな感じで良いのでしょうか
NTT(192.168.1.96-127)
KDDI(192.168.1.128-159)

route -p add 192.168.1.96 mask 255.255.255.224 192.168.1.5
route -p add 192.168.1.128 mask 255.255.255.224 192.168.1.10

よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: 2はタスクスケジューラで定期実行となるでしょうね。権限必要です。本当に可能かは分かりませんが。   3はコメント欄でやり取りするには無理で、たぶん大丈夫と思います、としておきます。前提として、事務所内の端末にはパケットが届いているが、戻りが喪失している、ということです。ご確認ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます
なるほど、タスクスケジューラでの定期実行ですか
ひとまず3の方法で試してみます
とても助かりました
ありがとうございます

Comment: よろしければ回答で解決したチェックを入れてください。別の疑問があれば新しい質問を立ててください。